# Sencha touch 2, multiple items carousel

Tags: sencha-touch-2, carousel

I want to make a carousel which every single slide is going to have 3 items, not an infinite one, just a regular carousel with multiple items showing up .

Does someone has an url, example or an idea how it was implemented .

Update:

**I hope this image helps:**

[image]

*PS:I want to use data store, for rendering the data, because on Portrait view I have to display 3 items instead 2*

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "every single slide is going to have 3 times"? Do you mean, you want 3 visible at all times, even when you swipe to the next?

Comment: Can you please explain your question in more detail? I didn't get your question ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe stupid. But couldn't you make the childs panels wich contains 3 items.
So in stead of scrolling through the items you scroll through panels which contain 3 items.

Comment: yes man, this is the way how I did , I even used the component seems be bi fine. Plus nobody else with another option

Answer (score 2):

Did you only want 1 new item to scroll into view? I have setup a multi item carousel with 12 images at a time, with 12 new ones coming into view on swipe if posting some code will help.

Don't forget this example is also useful too, although you did say not an infinite one:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/list-horizontal/index.html

:-)